# How to check if a form was already submitted with javascript and ajax to avoid multiple sending of the same form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

A form is a really interesting element in javascript or jquery (in this case).

Here's my problem:

JS:

```
const themeFolder = object_name.templateUrl;
const urlAjax = themeFolder + '/FormHandler.php';
const form = $('#contact-form');
const outputmessage = $('.output-message');

form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: urlAjax,
        method: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize() + '&submit=true',
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            outputmessage.append('<p>A message was sent successfully!</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if ($ok == true && isset($_POST['submit']) && empty( $honeypot )) {
    $json_tidy = json_encode($_POST);
    echo $json_tidy;
} else {
    echo 'something wrong';
}
```

Now, what I'm not getting is the fact that I can send the same form multiple times with the same values but I'm not finding a solution to send my form only once and disable the form right after having done that.

Probably I'm overthinking but for example, the json_tidy will post this result:

```
{"fname":"ma","lname":"ma","email":"ciao@ma.com","message":"ciao","honeypot":"","submit":"true"}</body>
```

Which doesn't make a lot of sense for me.

Plus in this case, I'm struggling in finding a value to identify as a counter for how many times I will send a form.

I can use return true and false, right after the form.submit(function(e) {} and at the and of the javascript, but it will only avoid to my js script to run and fire the php script, which is in my form:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="{{ theme.link }}/FormHandler.php" method="POST">
```

I'm wondering if anyone else had the same problem in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a boolean variable?

```
    // outer scope
    let hasSubmitted = false;
    //...
    form.submit(function(e) {
    if(hasSubmitted)return;
    hasSubmitted = true;
    //...
```

or:

```
const submitButton = $("#submit-button")

form.submit(function(e) {
    submitButton.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Actually, that's a jquery entity, so to disable the syntax is the following:

submitButton.prop("disabled", true);

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) event handler just after sending the form, so the form won't be sent again.

Depending on the jQuery version you are using, you can do that with

```
$form.submit(false);
```

Or:

```
$form.off('submit');
$form.on('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

Another option is to disable the submit button and, optionally, the input fields:

```js
const $form = $('#form');
const $message = $('#message');
const $submit = $('#submit');

$form.submit((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // Option 1: Remove submit event handler:
    $form.off('submit');
    $form.on('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault());
    
    // Option 2: Disable the submit button:
    $submit.prop('disabled', true);
    
    // Disable all input fields (optional):
    $form.find('input, textarea').prop('disabled', true);    
    
    // Add feedback message:
    $message.text('Sending message...');
    
    // Simulate request:
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Update feedback message:
      $message.text('The message was sent successfully!');
    }, 2000)
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}

#form {
  width: 50vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input,
textarea,
button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#message {
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" />
  <textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  
  <div id="message"></div>
  
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```